# Java dependency injection using ASM or CGLib

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-bytecode-asm, cglib, bytecode-manipulation

I have a fairly large Java code base (~15k files) that I do not have access to the source for, however, I would like to modify certain classes at runtime and inject code into certain methods to also call my code.

Due to technical issues, I can't decompile/recompile and go from there. The class files are loaded by native code and are extracted from a custom archive format and loaded using a custom class loader. I can however execute Java code in the context of their JVM instance fairly easily.

My goal is to do something like below:

For example, say in there code there is a class:

```
class Theirs {

    public Theirs() {
        //....
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Theirs";
    }
}
```

And in my code I have:

```
class Mine 
{
    public static Theirs theirs_ = null;
    public static void myMethod(Theirs theirs) { 
        theirs_ = theirs;
    }
}
```

I would like to modify *every* instance of Theirs to behave as such:

```
class Theirs { 
    public Theirs() {
        Mine.myMethod(this);
    }
}
```

So that I can then do something like:

```
System.out.println(Mine.theirs_.getName());
```

I thought that CGLib Proxies would enable this, but with Proxies, the overhead is high due to string comparisons for methods that may be called hundreds thousands of times a second and anyways, I discovered that in order to have an instance of an enhanced object, you need to instantiate them yourself.. IE: not all instances of the class you enhanced are actually enhanced such as:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Object proxy = Enhancer.create(Object.class, new HashCodeAlwaysZeroMethodInterceptor());
    System.out.println(new Object().hashCode());
    System.out.println(proxy.hashCode());

}
```

The first println prints a real objects hash, not 0 as intended.

So now I am thinking that what I need to do is write my own (or modify theirs) ClassLoader that looks for the classes I am interested in modifying, inject my modifications and go from there using something like ASM. (I've done something similar using JVMTI and C++, but the compile/debug process for that is extremely time consuming)

Before I do that however, I was hoping that there was something that worked similar to how CGLib proxies work, in that the library takes care of the required bytecode modifications, but that doesn't require me to actually instantiate an instance of said enhanced class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `CGLIB` is ideal for injecting Java code into Java classes -  but there are a couple of framework like f.e. javassist available which provide a Java centric way to inject code into non-sealed Java classes: http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

For example, I had to create a Plugin mechanism for a university course once where I used javassist therefore. Hope the code example is helpful: https://github.com/RovoMe/PluginApplication/blob/master/PluginFramework/PluginCore/src/main/java/at/rovo/core/classloader/InjectionLoaderStrategyDecorator.java

Comment: That looks interesting. javassist looks really easy to inject code with. I have a question though, how do you gain execution of your code?

Comment: so you need access to the jar of the app you are extending?

Comment: I mean, say the app you are extending is named foo. To run it, you do java -jar foo.jar. In the normal case, how do you add a plugin to foo.jar